# Changing color of an object in an image

Tags: image-processing, color

Consider the following image:

[image: Red ball in a non-red environment]

How can I change all red colors in this image into (for example) blue.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's a version using `Manipulate` with a `Locator` to pick the colour to replace. There is also a tolerance control which determines how wide a range of hues to replace.

```
i=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr7Tx.jpg"];

{h,s,b}=ColorSeparate[i,"HSB"];

colourchange[c_,from_,tol_,to_]:=Module[
{offset=Mod[c-from+0.5,1]-0.5},
If[Abs[offset]>tol,c,to]];

Manipulate[
ColorCombine[
{ImageApply[colourchange[#,ImageValue[h,pos],tol,ColorConvert[to,Hue][[1]]]&,h],s,b},
"HSB"],
{{to,Blue,"Change to"},Blue},
{{tol,-0.01,"Tolerance"},-0.01,0.5},
{{pos,{100,50}},Locator}]
```

[image]

Comment: You could also add a polygon defined by other locators, to define the mask of impact...

Comment: Or use another locator as a brush

Comment: ...and I see a full image-processing graphical suit a la Photoshop implemented in *Mathematica* coming up soon...

Comment: @Simon Woods: nice approach! I like that one but still: see the two people on the left hand side of the ball? The went blue too. How one avoid that?

Answer (score 59):

I wanted to change *only* the color of the ball, leaving all other red objects untouched:

```
getReds[x_Image] := First@ColorSeparate[x, "Hue"]
isolateSphere[x_Image] := SelectComponents[Binarize[getReds[x], .9], Large]
makeMask[x_Image] := Image@Graphics[ Disk @@ (1 /. 
                        ComponentMeasurements[isolateSphere[x], {"Centroid","BoundingDiskRadius"}]), 
                        {PlotRange -> Thread[{1, #}], ImageSize -> #} &@ImageDimensions@x]
getAreaToChange[x_Image] := ImageMultiply[i, ColorNegate@makeMask[x]]
shiftColors[x_Image] := Image[ImageData[getAreaToChange[x]] /. 
                                                      p: {r_, g_, b_} /; r > .3 :> RotateLeft[p, 1]]
finishIt[x_Image] :=  ImageAdd[ImageMultiply[x, makeMask[x]], ColorConvert[shiftColors[x], "RGB"]]

{#, getReds@#, isolateSphere@#, makeMask@#, getAreaToChange@#, shiftColors@#, finishIt@#} &
                                                       @Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr7Tx.jpg"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comparing side to side:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice. What should one change to change the from and to colors? Or it only works for red and blue?

Comment: +1 Nice. What would you have done if there were other instances of red in the picture that you did not want to alter?

Comment: @David In that case you'd need a mask

Comment: @Rojo In fact Red is the most difficult case, since it is at the beginning and at the end of the Hue[] table. Try  **Graphics[Raster[Table[{h, s, 1}, {s, 0, 1, .01}, {h, 0, 1, .01}], 
  ColorFunction -> Hue]]**

Comment: @DavidCarraher See edit

Comment: Very nice. It takes a surprising bit of code.

Comment: @DavidCarraher That happens usually in image processing. Things like "reddish" and "the big thingie in the middle" are not as easy to program as `CylindricalDecomposition[]` :)

Comment: I was wondering whether `EdgeDetect` would be helpful to limit the change of color to the ball.

Comment: @John Perhaps twisting it somehow. The illumination does not help.

Comment: The mask does not run for me. What's `m`?

Comment: @Emre It was a leftover from a previous version. Try the code now.

Comment: Congrats on your (soon to be awarded) populist badge! :)

Comment: @R.M Thanks!! :D

Answer (score 35):

A one-liner:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr7Tx.jpg"];

Image[ImageData[i] /. {r_, g_, b_} /; r > g && r > b -> {b, g, r}]
```

[image]

Comment: `ImageApply[RotateLeft, i]` have a same effect. :)

Answer (score 4):

## First Method

If you just want to get different color of your ball,but don't want to name the color.I will recommend you this solution,which makes your life easier.In the meantime,it will change other place's color,not just the ball,like [CSP's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4853/21532)

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr7Tx.jpg"];
Select[ColorCombine /@ Tuples[ColorSeparate[img], {3}], 
 ImageMeasurements[ColorDistance[ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"], #], 
    "Total"] > 8000 &]
```

[image]

You get 20 different color ball by a line code.

---

## Second Method

If you just want to change your ball's color with a specified color and want maintain other place,like [Dr. belisarius' answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4780/21532),I make a custom function for you to do this

```
ChangeColor[img_, color_] := 
 Module[{mask = 
    Dilation[
     DeleteSmallComponents[
      ChanVeseBinarize[
       KarhunenLoeveDecomposition[
         ColorCombine /@ Permutations[ColorSeparate[img]]][[1, 2]]]], 
     9]}, ImageAdd[ImageSubtract[img, ImageMultiply[img, mask]], 
   ColorConvert[
    ColorCombine[
     Prepend[Rest[
       ColorSeparate[ColorConvert[ImageMultiply[img, mask], "HSB"]]], 
      First[ColorSeparate[
        ImageMultiply[
         ConstantImage[color, ImageDimensions[img], 
          ColorSpace -> "HSB"], mask]]]], "HSB"], "RGB"]]]
```

**Usage:**

```
ChangeColor[img, #] & /@ RandomColor[5]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that the background change in the first solution, so I prefer the second one

Comment: @Wjx Thanks. :)

Comment: `ChanVeseBinarize[]` looks to be the key component here.