# Filtering pixels of a certain color

Tags: image-processing, color

*What is the best way to filter an image so that only the pixels close to a certain color are left?*

I've downloaded some satellite images from the web where a specific pixel color corresponds to a some type of crop. Thus I would like to filter out with Mathematica those pixels that are specifically for that color so I can next run ComponentMeasurements to obtain the area covered by those pixels.

I was trying to figure out what function to use or build that would just return an image with the pixels that match or are truly similar to the color provided.

Comment: Is your question a general image-processing question or specific to Mathematica?

Comment: See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4777/89) post, it might give you some ideas where to start.

Comment: What definition of "color" do you want to use?

Comment: [Here's another implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8577071/695132) (an earlier answer of mine).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzUdB.gif"];

{h, s, b} = ColorSeparate[i, "HSB"];

Manipulate[
 Column[
  {
   Graphics[{Hue[c], Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 40],
   ImageMultiply[i, 
    Binarize[Abs[Mod[ImageData[h] - c, 1, -1/2]] // Image, 
      tolerance] // ColorNegate]
   }
  ],
 {c, 0, 1},
 {{tolerance, 0.1}, 0, 0.5}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

<sub>[GIF image source](http://utopia.knoware.nl/users/eprebel/SoundAndVision/Engineering/ColorTest.gif)</sub>

Comment: Very nice.  Version 7 users will need: `{h, s, b} = ColorSeparate@ColorConvert[i, "HSB"];`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Good catch! The second argument (the color space) of ColorSeparate is a version 8 addition.

Comment: If you feel that my comment is beneficial, why don't you give it a vote?  This way useful comments do not get lost in noise.  If this mechanism is used properly this should reduce the need to delete comments, to pick up yesterday's discussion.

Comment: @mr.wizard Didn't cross my mind, but makes sense. Done.

Comment: Note that since `Hue` is periodic with period 1 you might want to apply a function to the image data of `h` that reflects this periodicity. For example you could do something like `Abs[Mod[ImageData[h] - c, 1, -1/2]]`. This way, when filtering on `Hue[0]` (which is equal to `Hue[1]`) you'll not only catch the points with hue `0 <= hue < tol` but also `1-tol < hue <= 1`.

Comment: +1 Great, but your current code has only 1 slider while images of interfaces have 2.

Comment: @Sjoerd Now try to identify a crop field with that!

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Vitaly I copied the wrong version.Corrected

Comment: @heike Good suggestion. It's now in there. What I still don't like is the fact that black and white parts are also selected, but that's an effect of the color space. Perhaps I should also remove parts with insufficient saturation.

Answer (score 7):

I investigated an alternative approach - a simple brute force technique, not as good as Sjoerd's.

```
satImage = ImageResize[
 Import["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons
 /a/ac/Bananal-Island-North-End-Landsat-25-07-1992.gif"], 300]
```

[image: satellite image from wikipedia]

```
find[pixel_, color_, tolerance_] := If[
   And[
    Abs[color[[1]] - pixel[[1]]] < tolerance ,
    Abs[color[[2]] - pixel[[2]]] < tolerance ,
    Abs[color[[3]] - pixel[[3]]] < tolerance ], pixel, {0, 0, 0}];

Manipulate[
 im = ImageApply[find[#, col, tolerance] &, satImage],
 {col, Blue},
 {{tolerance, 0.2}, 0.1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: manipulate]

Answer (score 4):

An answer to this question also appears in [this other answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4842/245), albeit somewhat hidden. So I've taken the relevant part of my answer there and put it into this function which extracts the desired color by setting all other colors transparent:

```
colorExpose[im_, col_, tol_: .005] := Module[
  {
   color = Apply[List, ColorConvert[col, "RGB"]],
   r = If[
     ImageColorSpace[im] != "RGB",
     ColorConvert[im, "RGB"], im
     ]
   },
  SetAlphaChannel[r,
   Binarize[r, (Norm[# - color] < tol) &]
   ]
  ]
```

Here are some examples of how the function can be used:

```
ra = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzUdB.gif"]
colorExpose[ColorConvert[ra, "CMYK"], Yellow]
colorExpose[ra, Hue[.5]]
```

These forms show that the colorspace doesn't matter for the supplied image or the color, because the function always converts to `RGBColor` before doing the comparisons. The tolerance for the color matching is supplied as a third (optional) argument.