# Image Processing: Car front detection

Tags: image-processing

**Background**

Image processing can be applied to car license plate detection problems see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_number_plate_recognition), [segmenting numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731810/segmenting-license-plate-characters), [belisarius's old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777677/license-plate-recognition-determining-color-range-for-pixel-comparison). Also, on this site once can use some techniques explained in these answers [4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91697/how-can-i-capture-a-rectangular-area-from-an-image), [5](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8794/image-processing-isolating-areas-of-an-image-with-internal-irregularity), [6](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9449/remove-image-background-of-headshot-in-mathematica) in order to find the license plate. I want to apply image processing techniques to **'Car front detection'** problem.

*The main idea is to find the license plate rectangle and then use the center to chop the car front with a given length and width*. Same sample images are:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

The desired output is the red clipped rectangle the size that might be adjusted once, but should use the center of the license plate vertically so that if needed I can mirror the half of the car.

> [image]

I have two main problems:

1. The license plate rectangle has to be corrected due to the camera
   angle. (by using e.g `PerspectiveTransform`)
2. To find the car front I have to clean the shadow of the car.

**The code up to now**

To find license plate:

```
img = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmONo.png";
bin = FillingTransform[ MorphologicalBinarize[ColorNegate@imgc, {.3, .5}], 1];


(* License Plate method 1*)
Thinning@Dilation[ Binarize[DeleteSmallComponents[
  LaplacianGaussianFilter[img, 3], Method -> "Cluster"], 0.05], 4]
```

> [image]

```
(* License Plate method 2*)
c = Closing[img, 5];
lic = DeleteSmallComponents@Binarize[TopHatTransform[c, 10], 0.25]
```

> [image]

Taken from @nikie's nice answer to this [Q](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19546/image-processing-floor-plan-detecting-rooms-borders-area-and-room-names-t)

```
rects = ComponentMeasurements[lic, "BoundingBox"];

growRect[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] := 
 Module[{checkRectEmpty, growSingleDirection, growSingleStep, cx, cy, 
   left, top, right, bottom, sizeEstimate, 
   size}, ({cx, cy} = Round[{x1 + x2, y1 + y2}/2];
   checkRectEmpty[{left_, top_, right_, bottom_}] := 
    Max[ImageValue[
       m, {cx - left ;; cx + right, cy - top ;; cy + bottom}]] == 0;
   growSingleDirection[size_, grow_] := 
    If[checkRectEmpty[size + grow], size + grow, size];
   growSingleStep[size_] := 
    Fold[growSingleDirection, size, IdentityMatrix[4]];
   sizeEstimate = 
    Abs[Round[{x2 - x1, y2 - y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1}/2 - 20]];
   {left, top, right, bottom} = 
    FixedPoint[growSingleStep, sizeEstimate, 20];
   Rectangle[{cx - left, cy - top}, {cx + right, cy + bottom}])]

finalRectangles = growRect /@ rects[[All, 2]]
Show[lic, Graphics[{Red, finalRectangles[[ ;; ]]}]]
```

> {Rectangle[{348, 230}, {420, 246}], Rectangle[{278, 193}, {478, 205}]}
>
> [image]

**Edit 1: Camera angle correction**

```
(*Select license plate component*)
c = SelectComponents[MorphologicalComponents[lic] , "Rectangularity", # > 0.5 &];

ang = ComponentMeasurements[c, "Orientation"][[1, 2]]; 
ImagePerspectiveTransformation[img, 
       ShearingTransform[ Pi + ang, {1, 0}, {0, 1}], PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image]

**Edit 1 end.**

To find shadow:

```
(*finding shadow*)
comp = MorphologicalComponents[DeleteBorderComponents@bin] ;
s = SelectComponents[comp, {"Centroid", "Area"}, #2 > 31000 &]  // Colorize
ComponentMeasurements[DeleteBorderComponents@bin, {"Centroid", "Area"}, #2 > 31000 &]
```

> ```
> {11 -> {{431.823, 165.048}, 32052.3}}
> ```
>
> [image]

**My questions are:**

1. How to find car plate rectangle and correct the image perspective?
2. How to remove the car shadow from the front view?

Any help and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Ha! _"Milangaz"_ is slang for schnitzel here :)

Comment: Could you show the desired output for those pictures?

Comment: Hehe, Here is LPG company :)  I'm getting hungry here ...  :P

Comment: @ belisarius I hope its clearer now.

Comment: Are all the photos taken with the same camera, so the angle from the camera to the road is always the same?

Comment: The road has two lines and for each lone there is a saparate cam. The images are from single cam.